# Changes not taken effect on device, but on simulator

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

after reading here for a long time and finding a lot of hints which helped me, I'm actually stucked with the development of my app.

I'm using Xcode 4.5 and have a tabbed application with four views.
Everything went fine since a few days ago.

I'm taking changes for example the icon of one tab.
I run simulator and eveything is OK.
When running the app on an iDevice the change of the image does not take effect. The old image and even name of the tab will be displayed.
Even leaving the old image and just changing in the tabbar controller in the storyboard the order of the tabs(instaead of tab 1, 2, 3, 4 for example 1, 2, 4, 3) it will not take effect on the device.
Deleting the app on the device does not effect.
Cleaning the project also does not helps.

What else can I try?

Also, for example, in my four views I'm using four web views.
If I resize on web view in e.g. 50x50, on the simulator it will be resized, but not on the device.
It's still centered and in full view (420x311)

I'm really looking forward to get some hints. I really don't know what else I can do

Comment: Are you starting the app directly through Xcode? Better clean: Cmd-Alt-Shift-K

Comment: Yes, most of the time I use CMD-B and than CMD-R.
Tested CMD-ALT-Shift-K (didn't know that, thanks) but still same effect

Comment: Are all your changes in some way connected to nib/xib files? Can you add some logging code in didFinishLaunching and see if it appears on the console?

Comment: Have you flushed the DerivedData folder?

Answer (score 0):

Hello eiko,

finally I found the error.
Has been my fault.

Simple as it is it was the storyboard, or to be more specific the localization (German and English).
In simulator(as it was set to English) I saw all the changes.
When I plugged an iDevice(set to German) it took only the storyboard in german, where most of the changes hasn't been take effect.

I deleted now one and work only with one.
My fault.

Thanks to eiko for asking the right questions!